# If 529 distribution is qualified expense, should I report it in tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 529-plan, college, education-savings

I received 1099Q and 1098T. The withdrawal was for tuition. I am not qualified for any education credits.

Can I not report this on my tax return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I not report this on my tax return?

Yes. It doesn't need to be reported.

Here's the [instructions for Turbo Tax](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tips/college-and-education/what-is-irs-form-1099-q/L7MAdcKz5):

> If the distribution doesn’t exceed the amount of the student's qualifying expenses, then you don't have to report any of the distribution as income on your tax return.